# Add a progressive bar at the bottom of recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, progress-bar, infinite-scroll

I am currently working on an Android application.
I have a RecyclerView that I am populating with making calls to a REST API.
The API is paginated, so I have managed to load the data progressively.
I'm adding data when the user scroll until reaching the bottom of the page.
Currently, I have fixed a progressive bar at the bottom of my main layout, below the RecyclerView. (I did this thanks to this post [Adding progressbar at the end of recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42523527/adding-progressbar-at-the-end-of-recyclerview))
This is working but the spinner renders on the text and I would like to avoid that.
Is it a way to fit the progressive bar at the bottom of the RecyclerView, as an item and make it disappear when new data are collected ?

Thanks.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, it is possible. Just add and use a new item **type** and layout for your progress bar.

When you want to start loading items, add this new item type to your item list. This cause that `RecyclerView` adds this progress bar layout to list as a new item. When loading completed, delete progress bar item and add all new items to list. Then progress bar will be gone and new items will be added.

**Side note:**

Personally I love `RecyclerView` for its multiple item type support. It is a great tool, and I love to use this feature for complex `RecyclerView` structures.